# Run SQL Server Standard 2017 Edition Together with SSRS 2017 Developer Edition

Tags: sql-server, sql, licensing, ssrs

Has anybody ever tried running **SQL Server 2017 Standard with SSRS Developer Edition** and had it worked successfully?

I'm setting up a client environment in Azure. This will be there production environment. We felt sql server 2017 standard made the most sense but they require SSRS. I downloaded SSRS but the 'free' options are express and developer. Before I tell my client they need to purchase a license I was curious if anybody out here knows if its okay to mix the sql standard with ssrs developer?

Mostly just curious **if its possible, or if there are performance issues/limitations trying to do this**.

Comment: It's likely that the license for Developer won't permit production usage. It's free to encourage you to build on it and then license the functionality you need for production. Will Express not work for you?

Comment: I appreciate the response. When you say Express, or you referring to the SSRS Express edition, or the version of SQL Server? If you're referring to SSRS I haven't tried installing either edition (express or developer) yet. I wasn't sure if it would work or if it violated some type of EULA.

Comment: Someone can probably tell you whether it works, but we have a long standing policy of [not answering questions about licensing](https://serverfault.com/q/215405/126632).

Comment: Understood, thank you. I gave it a shot and was able to install SSRS Developer with SQL Server Standard but I'll try to contact somebody about the EULA stuff.